# Recompiling src file from cowboy prompt gives undefined function compile

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I have my server running with

make run

Then I edited a file. Back in the cowboy terminal I type

```
(tunnel@127.0.0.1)2> c(clock).
Recompiling /root/tunnel/src/clock.erl
** exception error: undefined function compile:file/2
     in function  c:compile_and_load/2 (c.erl, line 259)
     in call from c:safe_recompile/3 (c.erl, line 235)
(tunnel@127.0.0.1)3> compile(clock).
```

it seems that the shell recognizes the compile shortcut but it lists it as undefined.

How do I recompile while the server is running?

I also tried `erlc src/clock.erl`, which gave me a warning using export all but didn't respond with any error.

Comment: That's strange.. `compile:file/2` should definitely exist. Does your project have a module named `compile` as well? That one may be overriding the system one.

Comment: Or he's running a stripped down release without the compiler application.